# Javascript Split Array, Split again & Keep Indexes the Same

Tags: javascript

I have list that I'm trying to split into an array.

The items in the list will not always follow the same pattern. Here's the example list:

```
TestOne__Test One|1
TestTwo__Test Two|1
TestThree
TestFour__Test Four
TestFive|1
```

First I split each item by the '__', which creates the parts array with parts[1] and parts[2] (for any lines that include the __

But, any list items that also contain the "|1" suffix, need to be split as well.

Ideally I will end up with a single parts arrays that looks like this (for each i):

```
parts = [TestOne, Test One, 1]
parts = [TestTwo, Test Two, 1]
parts = [TestThree, '', '']
parts = [TestFour, Test Four, '']
parts = [TestFive, '', 1]
```

Here's the first split:

```
var promptList = ['TestOne__Test One|1', 'TestTwo__Test Two|1', 'TestThree', 'TestFour__Test Four'];
for (var i = 0; i < promptList.length; i++) {
    var parts = promptList[i].split('__');
}
```

I have tried splitting all at once with regex:

```
var parts = promptList[i].split(/__|\|/);
```

But that just jumbles up the array indexes. I want all the parts[0] items to be the First part of the line item, and parts[1] to be the second part of the line item (if there is one) and parts[2] to be the '1' suffix (if there is one).

The syntax for each line is as follows:

```
*TestOne* = the data that is too be saved
*Test One* = the display text that is to be shown to the user if this value is exists, otherwise "TestOne" is shown
*1* = whether or not the value will be pre-selected
```

I'd like to be able to reference parts[2] and be sure that it's referencing the '1' value for each item. In the above list parts[1] for line 5 will be the '1' value.

Comment: Probably want `/__|\|/`

Comment: Your addition of `TestFive|1` fundamentally changes this question and also makes your requirements quite vague. Why should there be an empty string between `TestFive` and `1` and not one after `TestThree`?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in your regular expression. The regular expression you want is `/__|\|/` (or `/__|[|]/` if you want to use the character class to escape the vertical bar) to match *two* underscores (or one vertical bar), not an underscore-or-apostrophe-or-vertical-bar.

Comment: thanks for that. The problem I'm having is that while this technically 'works', if you look at line item 5 (TestFive|1), the "1" suffix is placed into parts[1] instead of parts[2].

Comment: Yes, of course: it's the second part, not the third part. If you need what you show for part5, you should also expect `parts = [TestThree, '', '']` and `parts = [TestFour, Test Four, '']`, which means it's time to change your post description, because you're expecting contradictory results.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Right, that's fine - done.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, it is not beautiful but it works:

```js
const data = `TestOne__Test One|1
TestTwo__Test Two|1
TestThree
TestFour__Test Four
TestFive|1`

const result = data.split('\n').map(line =>
  line.replace(/__|(\|.*)?$/,"__$1")
      .replace(/\||$/,"__")
      .split("__")
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

The first `replace()` makes sure there is always a `__` in the `line`. In case there isn't it will be inserted, either at the end or before a `(\|.*)` group - in case it exists (`?`). The second `replace()` then puts a `|` at the end of the `line`, in case there wasn't already one. Both `replace` calls will only replace their pattern at most *once*. The final `split()` will then always return an array with three elements, as requested by OP.

Here is a slightly modified version that will be more tolerant in case a second `__` appears after the `|`:

```js
const data = `TestOne__Test One|1
TestTwo__Test Two|1
TestThree
TestFour__Test Four
TestFive|1
Test six|2__3
Test 7__bla__3__4`

const result = data.split('\n').map(line =>
  line.replace(/__|(\|.*)?$/,"@sep@$1")
      .replace(/\||$/,"@sep@")
      .split("@sep@")
)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

`@sep@` is an arbitrary string that is expected never to occur in the input string (`data`).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

```
var promptList = ['TestOne__Test One|1', 'TestTwo__Test Two|1', 'TestThree', 'TestFour__Test Four', 'TestFive|1'];
for (var i = 0; i < promptList.length; i++) {
  var parts = promptList[i].split(/__|[|]/);
  if (parts[1] == '1') {
     parts[2] = '1';
     parts[1] = undefined;
  }
}
```